# Uncaught ReferenceError: jsPDF is not defined 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jspdf

I am working with `JQuery`. Now, I try to attach a link between `JQuery` and `jsPDF` but I get that error : `Uncaught ReferenceError: jsPDF is not defined`. I've import all `jsPDF` files.

I call this function to generate my pdf :

```
function toImprimer() {
      var doc = new JSPdf();
      doc.setFontSize(12);
      doc.setFontType('normal');
      doc.text(65, 73.60, 'Lastname');
      doc.text(65, 81, 'Firstname');
      // generate pdf
      doc.save('Lastname_firstname.pdf');
  }
```

And those are scripts I've imported in body tag :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/jsPDF/dist/jspdf.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
       $.getScript('assets/js/myData.js');
</script>
```

Comment: According to the [jspdf tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jspdf/info), it's `new jsPDF()`

Comment: @JaromandaX You are right. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the home page on https://parall.ax/products/jspdf

You should be using:

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
```

*Note the differences in case to your 'JSPdf'*

Comment: Correct. it should be new jsPDF();
Thank you @user817367